# Authorization problem with google maps plugin for flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm getting Authorization failure when trying to display a map in a flutter project using the [google maps plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter).

I get this error:

```
Authorization failure.  Please see 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how 
to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API(11104): In the Google Developer Console 
(https://console.developers.google.com)
E/Google Maps Android API(11104): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API 
v2" is enabled.
E/Google Maps Android API(11104): Ensure that the following Android Key 
exists:
E/Google Maps Android API(11104):   API Key: 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
E/Google Maps Android API(11104):   Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>; 
<package_name>):
```

I think I followed the instructions to the letter. It says here to ensure that Google Maps Android API v2 is enabled, but that API does not exist in the API list, I guess it was renamed in Maps SDK for Android, which I enabled.

I added the API Key and restricted it to Android apps, with the app footprint. Anyone else have had this problem?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, I put all the SHA-1 keys (debug,prod,google-signing) nothing works. were you able to solve it?

Comment: No. I moved to different areas of the app, and Ill get back to this at the end

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to go to the [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and Enable the MAP SDK API for android, make sure all the other sdk api's you use are enabled (MAP for ios, roads, places, etc), otherwise, if a call is made from your app, it will not get Authorised

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue..

First enable Android map sdk in google 
https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/overview?project=studious-optics-233010

and make sure your device internet on..

code...

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

 class MapDemo extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return MaterialApp(
  home: MapTest(),
);
}
 }

 class MapTest extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
// TODO: implement createState
return MapState();
}
 }

 class MapState extends State<MapTest> {
 Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

 static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(23.521563, -72.677433);

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
_controller.complete(controller);
 }

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Map Demo"),
  ),
  body: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: _center, zoom: 10.0),
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
   }

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check to make sure you have the correct SHA1 fingerprint authorized on the API Key you are using. Keep in mind that the debug version of the application (which will be the default when testing in Android Studio via emulator or test device) will be a different SHA1 fingerprint than the Release Version (which you would publish to the Google Play Store).

You can add multiple restrictions on a single API key to allow both the debug and release SHA1s to be authorized on the same API key.

Steps for finding the SHA1 for the release version can be found
    here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup#release-cert

Comment: I'm well aware of that. Tried everything, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

2 - Imprint of the debug certificate

**For Linux or macOS:**

$ `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

**For Windows:**

$ `keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Imprint of the production certificate

$ `keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name`

3 - Limit the use of your Android applications
     * Add your application ID
     * Add your sha1 previously generated

4 - Flutter clean

5 - Uninstall the application and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Go to APIs tab and see for Enabled APIS.
Need to add these